# Why doesn't 250 ml of tap water kept outdoor in -2 °C freeze to ice?

Tags: temperature, everyday-life, phase-transition, freezing

I kept 250 ml of tap water in a thin plastic container out in the garden. The outdoor temperature has been varying around -2 °C most of the night and rises only to 0 °C during the day. I was expecting the water to freeze to ice at night but it has remained liquid. One week has passed but the water has remained liquid.

Why doesn't this 250 ml of water freeze outdoors when the outdoors is -2 °C?

Comment: I assume that the water is pure. Dissolved impurities lower the freezing point. [See Blagden's law.]

Comment: How did you obtain this temperature measurement? Many common sensors have errors of about 2C on top of everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reported air temperature is only one aspect of the thermal environment that an object finds itself in.  The radiative environment is also important:

- Is it sunny during the day?
- Is there a (heated) building nearby?
- Has it been cloudy at night?
- Has the wind been calm or light?

It would be easy for a corner near a building to have an air temperature less than zero, but not allow the water to freeze if the building is warm.

Freezing is more likely when:

- Cold air is driven by the object (some breeze, not dead calm).
- The object has a wide view of the clear night sky.
- No buildings or structures nearby that can capture solar energy during the day and re-radiate it at night (or that might be explicitly heated).
- Not in contact with the ground.

Answer (score 0):

As it is tap water it might not be pure enough to become [supercooled](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph8xusY3GTM) or impure enough to cause a significant [depression of freezing point.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Solutions_and_Mixtures/Colligative_Properties/Freezing_Point_Depression)

That being so it might be that the ground on which the beaker is standing has enough of a thermal capacity to maintain the water in the liquid state.
That is, the ground on which the plastic container stands provides enough heat to keep the water temperature above freezing.

As a further part of your investigation I would measure the temperature of the water and of the surrounding air in the early morning before the ambient temperature rises above $0^\circ \rm C$.

If the plastic container is elevated above the surrounding ground then the air surrounding the plastic container might be warmer than the air which is lower than the plastic container.

Answer (score 0):

Supercooling of water is common.

There is many videos when water in PET bottles taken from a freezer is liquid, but freezes quickly when being poured out.

Water droplets in clouds do not freeze until about $-12 ^\circ \mathrm{C}$. Airliners passing clouds avoid cloud layers between the freezing point and this temperature. if they did not so, it could have tragical ends, in extreme cases in spite of applied anti freezing countermeasures.

Comment: Pretty sure my water is not supercooled because when I pour it out, it does not freeze immediately. I think my water does not freeze at all and I want to know why.

Comment: Slighly supercooled water does not freeze immediately.   Freezing 1 L of water releases as much heat as is needed to warm up water from 0 to 80 deg C.